# Inherit acessor in typescript

Tags: typescript, inheritance, accessor

I have a class A which possesses an accessor for an object which contains several string. 
The whole thing offers an easy way to get url to call a Vertx API.

My problem is that I would like to overload this API in a subclass B which inherit the class A.

Something like that :

```
class A {
    get api () {
        return {
            GET_LESSON : '/lesson/',
        };
    }
}


class B extends A{
    get api () {
        return _.extend(super.api, {
            GET_CALL : '/lesson/call/',
       });
   }
}
```

But it doesn't work, I get the error :

```
TS2340:Only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword.
```

Why do I have this error ? Is it an intended behaviour for Typescript Accessors ?

Comment: The error says it all. Your api getter is private to class A, so you cannot access it in class B.

Comment: @realbart http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20api%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GET_LESSON%20%3A%20'%2Flesson%2F'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20api%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20_.extend(super.api%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GET_CALL%20%3A%20'%2Flesson%2Fcall%2F'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D

Comment: @realbart I thought that every attribute or method was public by default. And making the accessor public in class A doesn't help.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/338

Comment: Yeah, as it says, only *methods* (not properties or fields) can be accessed via `super`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it an intended behaviour for Typescript Accessors

Yes. This is being tracked here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/338

Reason why its not supported yet: The current `super` lookup is really simple. Changing that has performance impacts covered in the issue as mentioned.